# P/Invoke: C# P/Invoking a C Function Returns Different Values Depending on Platform (X86 vs. X64)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, pinvoke

I feel ridiculous asking this question but I have a problem I've been looking at for hours now and I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

I have the following function signature defined in a C DLL:

```
__declspec(dllexport) _Bool __cdecl cs_support(int query);
```

I created the following P/Invoke signature equivalent in an internal class:

```
[DllImport("capstone", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern bool cs_support(int queryOption);
```

The internal class is defined in a .NET project that builds 2 assemblies, 1 for .NET Framework and one for .NET Core.

I create a small .NET command line application that loads both the .NET assembly and the C DLL and calls the function as follows:

```
var isSupported = NativeImport.cs_support(65503);
```

Now here is what is interesting that I can't figure out. When I call the function once if the application targets X86 and once if it targets X64 (hence either the X86 or X64 versions of the C DLL are loaded), I get different values! What is even more bizarre is the X64 version returns the correct value while the X86 version does not!

I have access to the source code of the C DLL and it has no processor directives to return different values for the same inpuut based on target platform. The C code is actually very straight forward should return the same value for the same input regardless of the target platform.

In addition, when I create a small C command line app to test, the same correct values are returned regardless of the target platform.

So it seems that only when the C DLL is loaded by a .NET and P/Invoked do I see this behavior!

So my question is, why is this happening? Is there some weird P/Invoke behavior that would cause this that I would have to watch out for?

I am running on Windows 10 64 Bit if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `_Bool`

Comment: Is there any math going on in the DLL that would overflow a 32-bit integer? Though, I suppose that would show up in the command line test, too

Comment: Can the dll log debug info, or can you attach a C debugger to the .net app to see what is happening in the dll?

Comment: Seems difficult to believe. Do you have a small reproducing project?

Comment: @PhilM I don't see any operations in the C DLL that would cause it to overflow and like you say if it did, it should show up in the C command line app as well. I can modify the C code to print debug info and rebuild and see.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I have a small reproducing app. What is the best way to share that?

Comment: Is your `_Bool` really based on `bool` and not `BOOL`? Please look here to understand the differences in marshalling the "native" `bool` and `BOOL`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool/ (`bool` is a C++ data type, whereas `BOOL` is a different data type declared by the Windows API)

Comment: Any where you can post a .zip. or if the important part is just a .cs, post it to pastebin.bin for example

Comment: @elgonzo So when I did a `sizeof(_Bool)`, it says its 1 byte. I am confused by the C spec though cause it says `_Bool` should be large enough to store `0` and `1` but it also says it should "correspond to the standard unsigned integer types". You might be onto something though because when I changed the signature of the C function to return a `int32_t` instead of ` `_Bool`, the problem goes away. So something is blowing up in the marshaling I think.

Comment: @PhilM So I debugged the C DLL from the C# app and the correct value is being returned by the C function. But it looks like marshaling (see my previous comment) to .NET is where the problem is.

Comment: @elgonzo The article you posted put me on the right track! If I annotate my C# P/Invoke signature with `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]` the problem goes away! Though I don't know why since both `sizeof(_Bool)` in C and `sizeof(bool)` in C# == 1 byte and I positive my `_Bool` is based on `bool` and not `BOOL`.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you but I got it working, albeit without really understanding why the solution works :)

Comment: @9ee1, the explanation is in the article i linked. Long story short, C has no `bool` data type. `bool` is a C++ data type. Since the Windows API (Win32 API) is based on C (not C++), it defines its own `BOOL` data type which is 4 bytes long. The .NET marshaller **by default** marshalls the C# bool to/from the Windows API `BOOL` (4 bytes) when p/invoking, unless specifically intstructed to do differently ;-)

Comment: Just for completeness, Win32 API also defines a `BOOLEAN` type (in addition to `BOOL`). Unlike the 4-byte BOOL, **BOOLEAN** _is_ a single byte. That may be what your _Bool type maps to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, it became clear that the problem was caused by the native function returning a `_Bool` value, with the type `_Bool` having a byte size of 1.

However, by default the .NET marshaller marshalls a C# `bool` to and from the Windows API data type `BOOL`, which has a byte size of 4 (also [see here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool/)).

To correctly marshall the single-byte `_Bool` value, the marshaller needs to be explicitly instructed to marshall the C# `bool` value as a single byte:

```
[DllImport("capstone", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
internal static extern bool cs_support(int queryOption);
```